# Creating PrivateKey Object from PKCS12

Tags: java, security, encryption, cryptography

I created private key from PKCS12 file with this command:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in test.p12 -nocerts -out privateKey.pem
```

How can I create PrivateKey Object from this `privateKey.pem` file now?

I tried using PKCS12 file itself with this code:

```
 KeyStore pfx = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12");
 pfx.load(new FileInputStream(P12), "123456".toCharArray());
 final Enumeration<String> aliases = pfx.aliases(); //this is empty
```

*`pfx.aliases()`* - was empty, I verified using keytool that it is really empty, no entries.

```
keytool -v -list -storetype pkcs12 -keystore test.p12

Keystore type: PKCS12
Keystore provider: SunJSSE

Your keystore contains 0 entries
```

My question is how can I create PrivateKey using code like this:

```
 public static RSAPrivateKey getPrivateKey(File privateKeyFile) throws IOException {
        byte[] keyBytes = new byte[(int) privateKeyFile.length()];
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(privateKeyFile);
        fis.read(keyBytes);
        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec spec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);// it works only with PKCS8
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        RSAPrivateKey privKey = (RSAPrivateKey) keyFactory.generatePrivate(spec);
        return privKey;
    }
```

The problem with this code it only works for PKCS8, I need something like this for PKCS12.

Comment: Have you tried by also storing a (self-signed) certificate in the PKCS#12? The P12 keystore is a bit limited on Java. Java normally only recognizes private key/certificate entries. Java 8 *could* give you better results, it has a specific project to give more PKCS#12 functionality.

Comment: How can I store certificate in PKCS12 file? I was given one certificate file along with this p12 file. I used that .cer file for getting public key.

Answer (score 3):

The only way I know is a bit low-level, but it works:

```
public PrivateKey getPrivateKey(File file) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    try (FileInputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream(file);
         DataInputStream dataStream = new DataInputStream(fileStream)) {
        byte[] keyBytes = new byte[(int) file.length()];
        dataStream.readFully(keyBytes);
        String temp = new String(keyBytes);
        String header = temp.replace("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n", "");
        header = header.replace("-----END PRIVATE KEY-----", "");
        byte[] decoded = new Base64().decode(header);
        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec spec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(decoded);
        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        return kf.generatePrivate(spec);
    }
}
```

This code assumes, that required key is a RSA key.

Comment: Hi thanks! but it is not working `java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException : DER input, Integer tag error`. The reason for this because we are trying to use PKCS8, whereas it is PKCS12. If this code worked, the above code I used will work without any problem.

Comment: Are you trying to feed .p12 file to it? This code is written for .pem, as the question states you need to create key from .pem.

Comment: No, I have a `privateKey.pem` file which I generated from `openssl pkcs12 -in test.p12 -nocerts -out privateKey.pem` command. the file has _BEGIN PRIVATE KEY_ and _END PRIVATE KEY_ string tokens. I just removed that token and used pure private key string.

Comment: If it's in .pem format, then it's not a PKCS12. PKCS12 representations have .pfx or .p12 format. So I daresay the root cause is a bit different here. Is it possible for you to share problematic .p12 or .pem for me to experiment a bit?

Comment: I found the problem. It was due to p12 file that I was given was not valid. Thank you very much!!!

Comment: @Jk1 PEM format is also known as ASCII armoring. It consists of a header and footer explaining what is encoded, and a base 64 encoded representation of the encoded data. This could very well be a PKCS#12 key container. In Java, you would first need to PEM decode the container to be able to use it as a PKCS#12 key store though.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using KeyStore Explorer (https://keystore-explorer.org/), which we use instead of Java Keytool (since I find it haunting to use).

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this will help someone.

Here is how you can generate a private key from your pkcs12 certificate file.

```
public PrivateKey getPrivateKey(String pathToPKCS12File) {
    try {
        InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(new File(pathToPKCS12File));
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
        ks.load(stream, "123456".toCharArray());
        return (PrivateKey) ks.getKey(
            ks.aliases.nextElement(),
            "123456".toCharArray()
        );
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //error
    }
}
```